# Accesing to jssor object implemented in document ready

Tags: javascript, jssor

I have to pause the autoPlay option in jssor implementation. The problem is that jssor object was implemented in document ready like the example:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var options = //STUFF;
    jssor_slider433265 = new $JssorSlider$("slider_container_433265", options);
});
```

I have not access to that code (I can only inject js code). Are there any method to access that object (all I want is to implement .$Pause() method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spoke with the jssor developer and the lib (very fast responses) hasn´t any getter for that situation (what is logical), so the only solution is to write to client to make the object global delcaring it ourside document ready or with window. sintax.